# How to use service API in ng2 translate in angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to use service API for ng2 translate in angular2.

On app load, need to consume API's response which will be translating the keys present in homepage. Any help is much appreciated .

Comment: Has you read the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate)?

Comment: yes I have read the documentation.  instead of using en.json I need to read response of service